# Create n number of variables (n is number given by user input) and have user input data for each created variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want to achieve is something like:

1. Ask user question: How many cars you have given on rent?
   (this is just a print statement.)
2. Now user should input from 0 to n. (Only numbers are allowed.)
   (This is user input)
    **3**
3. Now this will create 3 variables *and* for each such created variable it will ask to user to input values. e.g.

   `incomeFromCar_1` = **500** 
    `incomeFromCar_2` = **600** 
    `incomeFromCar_3` = **700**

Some clarifications:

- If user input 0, nothing should be done and script should exit out of current lines of code and go to next line of code.

  - ("How many times have you watched Friends? ---> What I mean by this is next line of code is entirely independent of this.)
- If user input does not input numbers, i.e. any string or even a float (`2.25`) it should through a error message saying "Please input numbers only".
- I could have posted a code, but it's only user input & I don't even know what to use for next line of code: i.e. a `for` or `while` loop, a `dict`, or a `list`?

System Info:

```
Python Version 3.5
Atom IDE
Windows 7
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: only user input i can't figure out what to do next.....to be honest, I know I am asking for basically entire thing.

Comment: This is a horrible approach - what possible good would it be to have the user input in variables that don't actually exist in your code?  The proper way to handle variable-length input is with a single container variable - probably a list in this case.

Comment: @jasonharper calling it a horrible approach is a bit unfair, OP is clearly very new to programming and hasn't come across things like lists. But yes, a list is the correct thing to use here.

Comment: See [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Comment: ...to be clear, "please write my program for me" questions are unwelcome here ("too broad" is the official close reason) -- so in marking this a duplicate, I did the courtesy of reading it as a permissibly narrow question, ie. how to dynamically create variables based on a loop.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, the answer to which discusses how homework (or homework-style) questions can be asked and answered in a way that's fully compliant with site rules.